# Using @Autowired service in quartz job

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm using spring boot and I have a service which stores/retrieves some data from DB. I want to use a quartz job which uses my service. I tried many suggestions from the internet to integrate quartz with spring boot, but it doesn't work. Can you help me pls?
Here is my code:
1) I added org.quartz-scheduler as dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2) This is my application.properties configured to use mysql as DB for my service:

```
    server.port=8281

    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
    spring.datasource.username=myusername
    spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

3) This is my service:

```
    @Service
    public class ReportService {

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public ReportService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }

        public List getPendingReports() {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE status = '" + ReportStatus.PENDING.name() +"'";
            ReportMapper reportsMapper = new ReportMapper();
            List reports = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, reportsMapper);
            return reports;
        }
    }
```

4) The scheduler class:

```
    import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
    import org.quartz.JobDetail;
    import org.quartz.Scheduler;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
    import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
    import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
    import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
    import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

    public class ReportScheduler {

        public void scanAndUpdateReports() {
            SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            try {
                Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
                scheduler.start();

                JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ReportsJob.class)
                          .withIdentity("reportsJob")
                          .build();

                SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                          .withIdentity("reportsTrigger")
                          .startNow()
                          .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                                  .withIntervalInSeconds(60).repeatForever())
                          .build();

                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

5) And my job class where I want to autowire the ReportService, but it is null:

```
    public class ReportsJob implements Job {

        @Autowired
        ReportService reportService; //this doesn't work (it is null) 

        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            List reports = reportService.getPendingReports();
            System.out.println("Reports:\n"+reports);
        }
    }
```

6) Right now I'm calling the scheduler from main method:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ReportAppBeApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ReportAppBeApplication.class, args);

            ReportScheduler rs = new ReportScheduler();
            rs.scanAndUpdateReports();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-quartz

Comment: Any exceptions ?

Comment: your job seems to have been created manually so autowiring can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is null because `@Autowired` only works in a `@Component`, `@Repository` or `@Service` annotated class.
Annotate your `ReportJob`class and make sure the map where you store the class is included in the `component scan` on startup. You can include the map for scanning with:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages={"folderOfReportJob"})`

This annotation should be added to an `@Configuration` or `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

EDIT:

If you don't want to make your job a component you can also get the bean manually through the `ApplicationContext` class. It goes like this:

```
private static ApplicationContext ac;
ReportService reportService = ac.getBean(ReportService.class);
```

Comment: I marked as the job class as `@Component` it still shows NullPointerException for reportService. I tried to use `@ComponentScan` on my packages, it's still the same.

Comment: try using `ApplicationContext` @ViorelCasapu

Answer (score 0):

I happened to find you a chinese blog writtig about a functioning implementation.
may i say you're trying to implement something like `spring-boot-starter-quartz`.

To Summary, you should defined your own `QuartzJobFactory` as to modify `createJobInstance` method adding `autowireBean` to newly create JobDetail instance.

something like,

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ReportsJob.class)
                          .withIdentity("reportsJob")
                          .build();
// Pseudocode here
autowiredBean(job);
```

working example,

```
    @Component("quartzJobFactory")
    public static class QuartzJobFactory extends AdaptableJobFactory {

        private final AutowireCapableBeanFactory capableBeanFactory;

        public QuartzJobFactory(AutowireCapableBeanFactory capableBeanFactory) {
            this.capableBeanFactory = capableBeanFactory;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object createJobInstance(TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
            //调用父类的方法，把Job注入到spring中
            Object jobInstance = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
            capableBeanFactory.autowireBean(jobInstance);
            return jobInstance;
        }
    }
```

```
@Configuration
class Configuration {
    @Bean(name = "scheduler")
    public Scheduler scheduler(QuartzJobFactory quartzJobFactory) throws Exception {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobFactory(quartzJobFactory);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        Scheduler scheduler = factoryBean.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

full post here: https://www.cnblogs.com/supiaopiao/p/14953978.html

Answer (score 0):

You could inject beans if you extends `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean` as mentioned in the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html).

Following code work for Kotlin

```
class EmailJob(private val myService: MyService): QuartzJobBean() {
    override fun executeInternal(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        myService.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In  my  case,  I  added  annotation  @DisallowConcurrentExecution . After that  I able to  access autowired services, smoothly.

```
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;

@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class InvoiceJob implements Job {
   @Autowired
   private RuntimeConfigurationService runtimeConfigurationService;
}
```